# Add json object to json array on assets

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to append a json object to my json array. So for i think it got it. But i'm trying to get the file file location on my json file. It's on my assets folder. here's the code and the error. How can i get the file location on my assets folder?

```
File fileJson = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir("/app"), "products.json");

03-04 15:26:33.609 6784-6784/com.elishanarida.json W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.elishanarida.json/files/app/products.json (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: You cannot modify a file you've put in `assets/` at runtime. You'd have to copy it to storage on the device, and work with that copy..

Answer (score 0):

Assets file only read and can't be wrote, you can get assets file by AssetsManager.Assets file is different from ExternalFilesDir,it is in your apk rather than the SD memery.So `new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir("/app"), "products.json");`is wrong.